# facebook format of POST object (to a wall)

Tags: java, facebook, json, post

I am using a java servlet to make a facebook POST of a link to a wall.

What I've gotten so far is that the facebook api's breakdown of the name/value pairs are such that the keys are always strings and the values are usually strings.

So for a POST that just posted a message the body of the POST would be:

```
message=hello
```

So the POST data would be of the same format as a GET request with name/value pairs.  And the values would be URL encoded.

However, I am having trouble with those values that are arrays or objects, like the "application" field of the feed post record.  How is this encoded?  How are arrays encoded?

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You would be doing a "POST" not a "GET". So the params would be not URL encoded. You are using Java you said? Your "POST" should look something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(https://graph.facebook.com/<username>/feed);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write("access_token=" + access_token + "&message=hello");
            writer.close();

writer.close();
```

Comment: I was going to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  So it would be URL encoded.  My question was about what to do with facebook objects like the "application".

Comment: Another question first. You are mentioning that you are using the feed connection? You do know that the feed is deprecated right? feed 

"Deprecated. Will be removed on March 1st, 2012. The application's wall." http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: Does this mean that applications will no longer be able to publish to a wall or a friend's wall, given the publish_stream permission?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

No you'll still be able to publish, but Facebook is pushing the Open Graph as the more appropriate way of interacting with Facebook. I suggest reading up on Open Graph and the Social Graph since the old connect methods are going away eventually.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/